# Transform standard output from Gradle's Exec task on the fly?

Tags: gradle

Is it possible to transform the standard output logs that a Gradle Exec task produces, on the fly?

We have a task executing a command line tool that takes about a minute to run which logs *a lot*. I would like to filter out just a few of those lines and log them to show progress without cluttering the build log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set your own `OutputStream` implementation with `Exec.setStandardOutput`. Or you could execute a shell command that runs the tool and filters its output.

Comment: Do you know if there's any publicly available example of such an `OutputStream`?

Comment: I'm not aware of any. Maybe Apache Commons or similar libraries provide `FilterOutputStream` implementations suitable for the problem at hand.